# PDF iTextSharp replacing logo

Tags: c#, itext

When I try to replace old logo (i3screen) to my logo, I got the following:

[image]

i3screen logo on the top by unknown reasons for me

my code:

```
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(model.InputFile);
        Document document = new Document(pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
            document.Open();

            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
            var pic = AddBlank(model.Blank);
            document.Add(pic);

            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, 1);
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

            document.Close();
            writer.Close();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }


    iTextSharp.text.Image AddBlank(byte[] blank)
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Image pic = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(blank);
        using (MemoryStream imgMs = new MemoryStream(blank))
        {
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imgMs);
        }

        pic.SetAbsolutePosition(10, 600 + (pic.Height / 2));

        return pic;
    }
```

probably, I can set layout for my logo, higher than layout of i3screen's logo or something else?

Comment: Have you tried adding the imported page first and the image thereafter?

Comment: It's full code.

Comment: Does that mean you have not tried? Then please do!

Comment: @mkl the same result

Comment: Ah, I only realize now that you add the image via the `Document` and the imported page directly to the `DirectContent`. This can cause resulting drawing orders different from content adding orders. Please try to add the imported page to `writer.DirectContentUnder` instead of `writer.DirectContent`.

Comment: @mkl thank you very much! Create an answer and I will vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the image via the `Document`

```
document.Add(pic);
```

and the imported page directly to the `DirectContent`

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
...
PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, 1);
cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
```

This can cause the drawing order in the result pdf to be different from the content adding order in your code.

To change that order please add the imported page to `writer.DirectContentUnder` instead of `writer.DirectContent`.